# Null issue needs an explanation

Tags: java

I am a newbie at programming and Java and this is my first null, I am a little bit confused because I do not know what happened is that kind of errors in coding? Or any thing else? Kindly needs your explanation in this situation and about null at overall in a simple way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter grades size :");

    int Size = input.nextInt();

    String[] y = new String[Size];
    int[] x = new int[Size];

    int Max = 0;
    int Min = x[0];

    String Max_studen = y[0];
    String Min_studen = y[0];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < Size ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter student name #" + (i));
        y[i] = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter student grade : #" + (i));
        x[i] = input.nextInt();

        if (x[i] > Max) {
            Max = x[i];
            Max_studen = y[i];
        } else if (x[i] < Min) {
            Min = x[i];
            Min_studen = y[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Max Student is: " + Max_studen);
    System.out.println("Max grade is: ");
    System.out.println(Max);
    System.out.println("Min Student is: " + Min_studen);
    System.out.println("Min grade is : ");
    System.out.println(Min);
}
```

Output is:

```
Enter grades size :
2
Enter student name #0
Sam
Enter student grade : #0
85
Enter student name #1
Samy
Enter student grade : #1
95
Max Student is: Samy
Max grade is:
95
Min Student is: null
Min grade is :
0
```

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment, but **please** put some care into formatting your posted code so that it conforms to standards. Your random placement of curly braces, random indentations, and extra spaces made me (and likely others) mis-read your code, something you don't want happening if you want help. If you don't know current Java code formatting standards, please Google this and then try to follow the recommendations.

Comment: And don't capitalize variable names. They should always start with a lower case letter.

Comment: i,ve edit it is that better :D , thanks for advice and  @connorp you alright capitalize variable names.is not good idea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a beginner, this is a tricky one. Let us walk through this code together.

The first important lines are those:

```
String[] y = new String[Size];
int[] x = new int[Size];
```

There is a major difference between those two arrays. `x` is an array of [primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), while `y` is an array of objects. Primitives have a well-defined default values in Java (typically `0`), so the array `x` is initialized with all cells containing a `0`. For objects there is no such thing as a default value. Since you can write your own class, Java does not know what a good default value for, e.g., a `Car` is. Therefore the [default value for objects is `null`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5). For the moment, let us define `null` as a value signaling "*This cell is empty*" <sup>1</sup>. So each cell of `y` contains `null` as its value.

Now to the next important lines:

```
int Min = x[0];
[...]
String Min_studen = y[0];
```

As explained earlier, `x` is initialized with all `0`. Concluding from this, `Min` is now `0`. We have a problem here because in a typical scenario we will never enter a grade `< 0` and therefore `Min` will never be overwritten. In genereal, if we are looking for some maximum or minimum, we should initialize them with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (for the maximum) or `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (for the minimum) respectively. There are similar constants for `long`, `float` and `double`. Theses constants typically avoid problems like the given one. Since `Min` is never overwritten, `Min_studen` is never overwritten either. The initial values of `y` are `null`s, as is `Min_studen`'s value.

---

Some remarks on your code:

- Variable names should be written in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).
- The `[]` of an array is typically written following the type, without a blank: `String[]` instead of `String []`.
- After a `{`, there should always be a linebreak.
- Variable names should be meaningful and descriptive. One could use `studentGrades` and `studentNames` instead of `x` and `y`.

There are many sites explaining coding conventions and style guides, some of them are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and [here](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) <sup>2</sup>. You might not want to look at them right now, but keep them in mind for later, if you got the basics of Java down and read them.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>The actual meaning of `null` is quite close to the description I gave, but the reasoning is a little bit more complex and requires the reader to have knowledge about heap- and stackmemory and what is stored where.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>There is no such thing as "the styleguid". You are of course free to define your own. Style guides are a means to make code easier to read. Please keep this in mind whenever you change your style guide or parts of it.</sub>

Comment: initialize min&max values  after the inputs loop and make a whole new loop has  solved the problem , makes sense  should i edit that in question code ?

Comment: @mostafamagdy please do not edit the problem out of the question. You can, however, put your running code under your question (via edit).

Answer (score 2):

`null` basically means that a variable or object is empty. Let's take a look at this section:

```
String[] y = new String[Size];
int[] x = new int[Size];
...
int Min = x [0];
...
String Min_studen = y[0];
```

At this point, `x[0]` and `y[0]` are still empty/null elements because no values were assigned to them. As a result, `Min` is 0, and `Min_studen` is null.

Skip forward to where `Min` and `Min_studen` are used:

```
else if (x[i] < Min) { Min = x[i];
    Min_studen = y [i];
}
```

Since no element in `x[]`is defined to be less than 0, this `if` statement will never run, causing `Min_studen` to display null when printed.

There is no clear solution as there are several logic errors, but you will need to make sure `Min` is not null so that the program will run.

Comment: `x[0]` is neither "empty" nor `null`. Primitives have a well-defined default-value in Java.

Comment: For int, would the default value be zero?

Comment: [Look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the insight. I always assign explicit values to variables, so I learned something new here :)

Comment: Assigning values to local variables is still necessary. Only attributes are assigned the default value implicitly. For me, it is good coding style to assign each value explicitly, but when working with e.g. arrays, it is good knowing that the array is not initialized with random values (like in C/C++) or something else.

Answer (score 0):

`null` basically means that the variable hasn't been set to anything yet so it is pointing to a special place in memory called `null`. You can read more about it here: http://www.programcreek.com/2013/12/what-exactly-is-null-in-java/

I think that your specific issue comes from this code:

```
if (x[i] > Max) {
    Max = x[i] ;
    Max_studen = y[i];
} else if (x[i] < Min) {
    Min = x[i];
    Min_studen = y[i];
}
//x[i] == Max???
```

You don't have a case for `x[i] == Max`. Add that case (possibly by modifying your current case to `x[i] >= Max` and that should fix the null issue.

Comment: I think the null error is caused by `Min` because `Max` at least has an initial value of 0. However, you are absolutely right in that `Max` is not used properly.

Comment: This is not the issue. The issue is, that `Min` is initialized (implicitly) with `0` and no grade `< 0` is enterered...

Comment: i replaced it,s initialized as Max and the same occur

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is x[0] and y[0] are not initialized. Hence Strings y[0] is stored as NULL.
x[0] is stored as 0.

You need to insert extra condition to initialize x[0] and y[0] with correct parameters.

> if (i==0) {
>   Max = x[0];
>   Min = x[0];
>   }

Check the code-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter grades size : ");

    int Size = input.nextInt();
    String[] y = new String[Size];
    int[] x = new int[Size];

    // Initialize string to store student names and grades
    // Student[0] for highest grade
    // Student[1] for lowest grade
    String[] Student = new String[2];
    int Max = 0, Min = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < Size ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter student (" + (i) + ") name : ");
        y[i] = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter student (" + (i) + ") grade : ");
        x[i] = input.nextInt();

        // This extra condition was missing in the above code.
        if (i==0) {
            Max = x[0];
            Min = x[0];
        }
        else {
            if (x[i] > Max) {
                Max = x[i] ;
                Student[0] = y[i];
                }

            else if (x[i] < Min) {
                Min = x[i];
                Student[1] = y[i];
                }
            }
        }

    System.out.println("Student with highest grade is: " + Student[0]);
    System.out.println("Max grade is: " + Max);
    System.out.println("Student with lowest grade is: " + Student[1]);
    System.out.println("Min grade is : " + Min);

   }
}
```

The output of the above program is here-

```
Enter grades size : 
3
Enter student (0) name : 
David
Enter student (0) grade : 
34
Enter student (1) name : 
Sam
Enter student (1) grade : 
42
Enter student (2) name : 
Nancy
Enter student (2) grade : 
25
Student with highest grade is: Sam
Max grade is: 42
Student with lowest grade is: Nancy
Min grade is : 25
```

Hope it helps..